# Confusion on connecting to either Oracle SQL Developer Databse or Oracle 11G?

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on a school project requiring me to use a our schools server as a database. They have an Oracle 11G Standard Server. I'm using Putty to tunnel data to Oracle SQL Developer. Once I've logged into our schools server and setting up Oracle SQL Developer to create a sample table called "USERS".

Now I'm writing a basic C# application to access that data but I'm confused on where to connect to. Would I connect to my schools Oracle 11G server(where I presume my table resides)? Or does it reside on my Oracle SQL Developer?

Apologies if I'm a little vague on it as I'm not sure how to phrase it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer is a developer tool, not the Database.
Your table resides on the 11G.